# Using Java merge to sum a number in a Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

I have a variable

`Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> movieToStateCount`

It will look a little bit like

```
"movieToStateCount": {
    "Monster's Inc": {
        "Alabama": 1500,
        "Ohio": 5,
        "Hawaii": 715
    },
    "Wall-E": {
        "Alabama": 30000,
        "Ohio": 5000,
        "Hawaii": 14589
    }
}
```

The way that I get these numbers is by iterating over a database such that whenever I get a new entry I want to add 1 to my Integer in my movieToStateCount. If I were just updating stateCount I could do something like

`stateCount.merge(state, 1, Integer::sum);`

But, is there a way to do this merge over the map of maps? Or, do I need to just go in and do the null check myself?

Thanks,

Comment: Is not clear to me what exactly you're iterating. Please show your loop.

Comment: Its not clear from the documentation that you can safely gang the merge operations as there is a chance one will return a null value. I'd recommend a simple loop to find or set the "movieToStateCount map and perform the merge with the result.

Answer (score 2):

Came up with the following function and a little test in main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> movieToStateCount = new HashMap<>();
    addTo(movieToStateCount, "Oldboy", "Texas");
    addTo(movieToStateCount, "Oldboy", "Texas");
    addTo(movieToStateCount, "Oldboy", "Alabama");
    addTo(movieToStateCount, "LOTR", "Somewhere");
    System.out.println(movieToStateCount);
  }

  private static void addTo(final Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> movieToStateCount,
          final String movie, final String state) {
    movieToStateCount.merge(movie, new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{ put(state, 1); }},
        (m1, m2) -> { m1.put(state, m1.getOrDefault(state, 0) + m2.get(state)); return m1; });
  }
```

Regarding the original question, didn't come up with a solution that would allow not to check for null, because `getOrDefault` effectively does that.